# Why can I access my IIS websites from internal LAN, but not externally when going over HTTPS

Tags: windows, ssl, iis, iis-8.5, sni

I have an IIS8.5 which hosts about 10 Websites. I also have a EV-SSL certificate from GoDaddy and a "normal" SSL Certificate signed by GoDaddy which I use for my sites. To get this working I had to setup SNI and force it to make sure the request of a client opens the correct site.

Now when I go to https://example.com from internal Network, everything works fine. If I do the same from external, it doesn't work. BUT when I go to http://example.com (not https), then I can access the site also from external networks.

If I go to https://example.com from external, I get connected to the server, but I only see the default IIS Page, not my requested Website.

Ports are open on both physical & windows firewall.

Why is that? I guess it's an issue with SNI but I can't get it working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi SimonS,

Are there any errors/entries on the w3svc logs when you had attempted to visit HTTPS/External? Perhaps the log files might be able to shed a little more light on this topic.

Comment: @MichaelFeng Hi Michael - no i didn't find anything useful in the LogFiles and also not in the EventViewer